# How to set a default ObjectId for a relation using prisma/mongodb

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next.js, prisma

I'm having trouble understanding how to set a default ObjectId for a Displate model that has a relationship with the User model. I want to push displates into the collection but it's not letting me do so without a userId which makes sense because it's required, but then I don't know how I'd push displates initially (before a user likes it and saves it for later).

The userId is only available after they log in (using getSession, using Nextjs, Next-Auth) and so I need an initial value for the userId to add it into the db.

I'm new to Prisma, so if I'm doing something incorrectly, please let me know!

Here's my User and Displate model and POST logic:

```
model Displate {
  id                 String @db.ObjectId @id @default(auto()) @map("_id")
  userId             String @db.ObjectId
  img                String
  finish             EFinish @default(MATTE)
  frame              EFrame @default(NONE)
  size               ESize @default(MEDIUM)
  price              Int? @default(44)
  title              String
  category           String

  user               User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id              String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name            String?
  email           String?   @unique
  emailVerified   DateTime?
  image           String?
  hashedPassword  String?
  createdAt       DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt       DateTime @updatedAt
  favoriteIds     String[] @db.ObjectId

  accounts        Account[]
  displates       Displate[] 
}



import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import prisma from "../../libs/prismadb";

import getCurrentUser from "@/app/actions/getCurrentUser";

import { getPrice } from "@/app/utils/getPrice";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

  if (!currentUser) {
    return NextResponse.error();
  }

  const body = await request.json();

  const { img, title, category } = body;

  Object.keys(body).forEach((value: any) => {
    if (!body[value]) {
      NextResponse.error();
    }
  });

  const displate = await prisma.displate.create({
    data: {
      img,
      title,
      category,
      userId: currentUser.id,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(displate);
}
```